# User Persp implementation

Tags: 3d-view

Is the User Persp implemented as an invisible camera ?
When I rotate the User Persp with middle mouse button, does the entire world rotate or just this camera ?

Comment: It's not a camera you're looking through. The MMB rotates the view around a defined point in the 3D viewer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, a virtual camera is implemented in Blender. Blender users a GL library which implements it in some other way underneath though.

Could you tell what you are trying to achieve with this?

Edit:

(This is what I have gleaned by reading some of the source. If someone more versed into it can correct me, he or she should feel free to.)

If you dig into blender/editors/space_view3d/, you can find the actual implementation. In summary `RegionView3D` objects hold the reference to the area's perspective (and by extension what you refer to as a virtual camera) in the `persp` member variable. The reference to the physical camera object is held by `View3D` objects. These may or may not be the same. (Or rather the `persp` derived from `View3D.camera` may or may not be the same as `RegionView3D.persp`.)

Here is the `view3d_setobjectascamera_exec` function's code. It manipulates both cameras. I am on a phone right now, and I can only post a screenshot. It is from the 2.6 branch found on launchpad.

[image: view3d_setobjectascamera_exec]

Comment: Only understand some implementation details